# How does X% Chance of Finding Magical Items work for a party?

Tags: diablo-iii

If I have an item with a X% increased chance to Finding Magical Items (3% in this case), does this apply only to me, or does that bonus apply to my party members as well? Could you end up stacking this with your teammates or your followers to provide a decent chance of better items overall?

If I give a piece of equipment to a follower with this bonus, what will happen? Will their bonus stack with mine? The [Followers pages](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/follower/) don't specify anything in regards to this nor is there any information on the [Game Guide](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/game/) that I could find.

[image: Scouting Gloves with 3% Better Change of Finding Magical Items]

Comment: Ready to reopen? Here's the answer (in a nutshell): In a party, your individual Magic Find bonus (MF) is **the average of your group's sum MF** (i.e., total MF divided by size of party).[1](http://diablo.incgamers.com/blog/comments/magic-find-and-gold-find-now-shared-through-the-party) [2](http://d3domination.com/diablo-3-guides/magic-finding-in-diablo-3/)

 Solo, you get 20% of your follower's MF[3](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/4079626032#13) stacked with your own (unshared) MF.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

As of the 1.04 patch on 8/21/2012, each party member gets their own magic find and gold find value applied to the items that drop for them.

Prior to 1.04, magic find in a party was averaged between party members.  So if you had a 4 person party, one had 40%, one had 20%, and the other two had none, everyone would have an effective magic find of 15% for their own drops.

The same thing applies to gold find bonuses and bonuses to XP.

For single player with a follower, you get your own value, plus 20% of the bonuses on your follower's gear.

[Source](http://www.diablofans.com/blizz-tracker/topic/218401-follower-gold-magic-find-equipment/)

Comment: The Sources are no longer available.

Comment: @Michel Indeed, they must have been on the beta forums.  I'll try to see if I can find another official source, but the information is still accurate.

Comment: From playing, the % XP Bonus -may- indeed be averaged across all people within the game. The straight up +xp/kill however is not. My brother and I have proven this one time and again.

Comment: I don't think this is true (anymore).  From your source: *"The amount displayed is your share of the bonus"* - however, the amount displayed is different for every player, meaning we *don't* all have the same magic find!  Anecdotally, I just played for several hours with a friend who has much lower magic-find than me; in that time, **I got 12 rares and a legendary, and he got 1 rare**.  It *could* of course have just been due to chance, but with such a large discrepancy, I highly doubt that.

Comment: @BlueRaja Were Nephalem Valor bonuses involved at all?

Comment: @bwarner: No, we are only level 20 *(but we are playing on hardcore, maybe it's different there?)*

Comment: That's a discrepancy.  I've done extensive tests in Ponies, with me at 120% and my friend at 0%, never once in those trials have I received significantly more loot or Gold.  It's averaged.

Comment: This is not true. Apparently (empirically) everyone has his own maigc find to himself. Siminilar to @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft s results, when I play with a friend who has high MF whereas I do not, he gets better gear more frequently, so he always needs to teleport to town more often to unload.

Answer (score 9):

**Gold and Magic Find (GF/MF) bonuses are individual** (no longer shared or averaged in a party).<sup>[1](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/6923456/104_Systems_Preview-8_10_2012) [2](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/6470967433)</sup>

Solo, **20% of your follower's MF, GF, and +Exp bonuses** stack atop your own.<sup>[3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/66416/21177)</sup>