# Do players only see loot usable by their class?

Tags: diablo-iii

Is there any logic to determine what "types" of item a player can see? Is it according to his or her class? (e.g. a Barbarian won't see Witch Doctor drops?)

Comment: I'm not sure you're using the word "droppings" correctly.

Comment: Thanks, and sorry about the mistake, i now see what i did :) Feel free to correct any other mistake

Comment: There are 3 different questions here, and they should be asked separately. However, be aware that the 3rd question has already been [asked and answered](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/49461/how-does-x-chance-of-finding-magical-items-work-for-a-party) on this site.

Comment: Your first question seems to fall under "Why did they design it that way", which is off-topic on our site.

Comment: I've removed your first and third question. As Oak stated, the third question was a dup.The first was a "Why did they design it that way?". Although it is something we could answer, it's not a gaming problem but a game *design* problem, and as such is off-topic on our site. However, a more generic version of your question, "What are the advantages to player specific loot?" would be on-topic on our sister site, [Game Development](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/). So you may wish to ask that there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The drops are still random and not related to your class. So as Barbarian you can get Witch Doctor items.