# Is boss loot stacked?

Tags: diablo-iii

I've seen [this other question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/65474) which works out generally, but in the specific case of boss drops, are things stacked in your favour for any bosses/difficulties? I've recently started two monks and a barbarian and I've had two fist weapons and a sickle drop from Leoric, so it's gotten me thinking about this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the first kills on a major boss at Normal difficulty; you are guaranteed 2 rares as drops (regardless of MF etc.) Also a [comment here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67386/what-is-an-effective-strategy-for-farming-yellow-drops/67391#comment94466_67391) suggests that one of them will be a class specific rare, which would explain the fist weapon drops for monks.

Answer (score 2):

No, the only "stacking" is for your first kill of a boss on Normal difficulty.  In that instance you have a higher chance of getting better items.  It still does not affect item type.

Basically you got lucky, so enjoy it. :)