# Do the bonus to health globes work also on items equipped by my companions?

Tags: diablo-iii

If I have an item that gives a bonus on health globes that I  pick up, does this bonus work also if I give said item to my follower?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What item bonuses apply to my follower?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66380/what-item-bonuses-apply-to-my-follower)

Comment: Not a duplicate. I think the OP is actually asking a specific case of the inverse question: "What bonuses on my follower's gear also applies to me?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading the bonus incorrectly.

The bonus applies to the amount of health the wearer receives from the health globe and has nothing to do with who picks it up.

To answer your question, when you (or anyone in your party) hits a health globe, the companion gains more health due to the item bonus.