# Does a companion gain experience for me?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What item bonuses apply to my follower?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66380/what-item-bonuses-apply-to-my-follower)

For example, Scoundrel has an item that has a magic property : "Monsters killed grant +9 experience"

Does he gains the experience for himself or it is the experience that i get? or both?

Comment: The answer is at http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/49461/how-does-x-chance-of-finding-magical-items-work-for-a-party/64732#64732

Comment: @bwarner: Not everything on follower adds 20% benefit, are you sure +exp works that way?

Comment: @Alok Yes, see the source linked in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes , items the a companion has on him IE. +exp will benefit yourself aswell as them.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, for the both of you**: the full exp bonus for your follower, and +20% of that bonus for you.<sup>[1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/66416/21177)</sup>