# Does magic find on followers do anything?

Tags: diablo-iii

Is there any value in equipping +MF items on my followers versus flat combat bonuses (damage/health/etc)?  Can I give them the MF items so I can do more pew pew?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does X% Chance of Finding Magical Items work for a party?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/49461/how-does-x-chance-of-finding-magical-items-work-for-a-party)

Answer (score 9):

[You get 20% of the MF found on your follower.](http://www.diablofans.com/blizz-tracker/topic/218401-follower-gold-magic-find-equipment/) Gold Find and +EXP, too.

Comment: Can you update this answer with respect to the new updates?

Comment: @Shahbaz as far as I know from the [contributed data](http://www.diablofans.com/best-content/#S2-5) the MF rate inherited from follower equipped has not changed. The [patch notes](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/7029347/Patch_104_Now_Live-8_21_2012) doesn't mention follower MF rates from equipment changing.