# Do follower bonus stats affect loot that is dropped for me?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does magic find on followers do anything?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66659/does-magic-find-on-followers-do-anything)

There are two stat categories that affect loot that is dropped - gold and magic find. If I give my follower items boosting these stats, does that count towards the loot I see?

This is assuming an active follower.

Comment: I think it is. I didn't see that question in my initial search. [This question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/49461/how-does-x-chance-of-finding-magical-items-work-for-a-party) looks like the most accurate version of what I'm looking for.

Comment: No worries.  This question will be closed, but not deleted for that very reason.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.diablofans.com/blizz-tracker/topic/218401-follower-gold-magic-find-equipment/

According to the devs: The amount displayed is your share of the bonus. You get 20% of your follower’s Magic Find, Gold Find, and + to XP.

Currently, Magic Find, Gold Find, and +XP bonuses are averaged across the entire group.