# How does X% Chance of Finding gold work for a party?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does X% Chance of Finding Magical Items work for a party?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/49461/how-does-x-chance-of-finding-magical-items-work-for-a-party)

I was reading [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/49461/how-does-x-chance-of-finding-magical-items-work-for-a-party). Works the same way for gold or is it different? Could someone provide a explanation for this?

Comment: The accepted answer specifically says it applies to gold find as well.

Comment: Looks like it does o.O" I read that and didn't saw it. I was going to delete the question, but it's good milestone ...

Comment: @MichelAyres don't delete it, still good for SEO

Comment: @NickT I'll not =) I was going to but them I though that like I was lost with this, someone may have this kind of problem too. as I said, it's a good milestone =)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it could be more prominent in the accepted answer on your linked question, but as bwarner points out: "magic find in a party is averaged between party members...The same thing applies to gold find bonuses and bonuses to XP."