# Does my sentry use any magic find or any other ability?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-demon-hunter

I've started using a sentry now that the skill is unlocked and I'm wondering if anyone knows if group or personal magic find and gold find bonuses are added to  any kill shots it gets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Magic and Gold Find have nothing to do with who gets the killing blow.

If the mob dies, your Magic and Gold Find affects the loot it drops. It has nothing to do with whether you killed it, your follower killed it, your pet killed it, or another player killed it. (Though in a group, your Magic and Gold Find is [averaged across the party.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/49461/how-does-x-chance-of-finding-magical-items-work-for-a-party))