# Diablo 3: Monster kills only on last hit? + drop question

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does X% Chance of Finding Magical Items work for a party?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/49461/how-does-x-chance-of-finding-magical-items-work-for-a-party)

i was wondering if you get your mob killcount increased by:

last hit?
damage inflichted but not last hit?
just standing near a kill?

Why i came up with it, i play with a mate and he does the damage and i do more tanking and less damage.
He got 4 legendaries in 3 runs and me got 0. Which was then his 15-20th in the whole game time.
While i only got 4 legendaries during the whole game in almost the same time.

During the game i always got 150-200% mf more than him 348% my peak value.
So we came up with the idea that last hitting minions affects the drop rate.

Or is it really only luck?

Comment: Everyone gets drops according to their own MF.  It doesn't matter who kills the monster.

Comment: legendaries are very finicky.  Sometimes I don't get any for days and then I get 3-4 in 1 run.

Comment: so its really my bad luck in this game...